# How to construct confidence interval out of a sample with small number of events?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, biostatistics, small-sample

I'm analyzing the results from an epidemiological study, where I have a sample of 2k persons with their respective ages and whether they were detected with a disease or not by different technologies. Those with the outcome of interest are a small number, around 10 individuals.

I would like to estimate the mean of such detected cases in the total population (to ultimately calculate a detection rate) with its corresponding confidence interval.

So far I simply made a bootstrap to get an estimation on the variation of these 10 outcomes, but this way I lose information on their ages and the other technologies, which is relevant because, if possible, I would also like to know the variation expected in the age distribution from these 10 cases, to do an analysis on the mean and variation expected of detected cases per age groups that I define categorically. For example, in the observed data I have 4 detected cases among persons below 50 years-old, 5 between 50 and 80, and 1 above 80+. This way I know the detection rates per category, but since the numbers are low I would like to have an idea of how wide the margin of error is.

Is there a proper analytical way to do it?

Comment: You forgot to say about which parameter you are concerned.

Comment: Your question is puzzling, because it *reads* like a straightforward confidence interval for a count, but the reference to "... information on their ages and the other technologies" suggests you're trying to do a more detailed analysis that you haven't yet described.  Which is it?

Comment: @whuber you're right, I thought that maybe I could figure out the more detailed part based on solving first the total count part but now I added more details. Hope is more clear.

Comment: Those are legitimate aims but you're probably aware your data are limited.  Note, too, that there's no need for a bootstrap here or -- almost equivalently -- you can carry it out directly with simple formulas rather than through sampling.  If you need specific advice, then you need to state specifically what you mean by "variation expected ... per categorical age groups."  It will be important to limit the hypotheses you test as much as possible, because you're likely to get many false results otherwise.

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I added more details, hopefully that makes it more clear.